# iPad app, HTML5, rotating for landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

If an iPad app basically hosts Webviews, and within those webviews I load some html5 docs, would there be an issue with rotating the device and rendering the UI in both landscape and portrait? 
By issues I means the HTML5 do I have to do any special handling for it as I rotate the webview? should I build two html docs one for portrait and one for landscape mode? and if so does that mean when rotating I have to load one into the webview and pause the UI until that is done?

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is a subclass of UIResponder -- from which you can capture motion events such as tilting/rotating. So assuming you find trouble with your code down the track, you can do something about it

You can also use UIDevice to get more information about the device's orientation